# Next.js build command gets stuck sometimes in Ubuntu 20.04 AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, next.js

When I run `next build` in my server, it gets stuck here, and the website also crashes and turns into a 504 Gateway Timeout error:

```
info  - Loaded env from /home/ubuntu/MYPROJECT/.env
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: future.webpack5 option not enabled https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types  
info  - Using external babel configuration from /home/ubuntu/MYPROJECT/.babelrc
info  - Creating an optimized production build..
```

This does not happen all the time, maybe 1 time every 5 to 10 deployments.

I then have to stop and start the EC2 instance. Right after the build command always runs very quick. Which could mean I have memory issues in the server? How could I resolve this?

I have a t2.micro instance with 8GB of storage.

```
Usage of /:   76.2% of 7.69GB
Memory usage: 50%
```

Could be that upgrading resolves this issue?

Comment: My one gets 'Killed' after a while. Have you found a fix?

Comment: Have you fixed it ?

Comment: @GhyathDarwish I didn't find the fix, please share it here if you do :)